# I am getting error undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass in Rails for updating image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My controller

```
def update
    handled_error_fields %i(location address1 address2 name name_kanji gender prefecture_code tel zip_code).collect { |s| :"primary_address.#{s}" }

    if params[:salon].present?
      if params[:salon].present?
        if params[:salon][:tel].present?
          tel = params[:staff][:tel]
          params[:staff][:tel] = NKF.nkf('-W -w -m0 -Z0', tel)
        end
      end
      if params[:staff][:email].present?
        email = params[:staff][:email]
        email.gsub!(/。/, '.')
        params[:staff][:email] = NKF.nkf('-W -w -m0 -Z0', email)
      end
    end

    if params[:staff]["staff_image"].present?
      @staff_image = StaffImage.find_by_staff_id(current_staff.id)
       if @staff_image.blank?
        @staff_image = StaffImage.new 
        @staff_image.staff_id = current_staff.id
        @staff_image.legacy_user_id = current_staff.legacy_user_id    
        @staff_image.image = params[:staff]["staff_image"]["image"].read
        @staff_image.save!
      else

        @staff_image.image = params[:staff]["staff_image"]["image"].read
        @staff_image.update_attribute('image', @staff_image.image)
       end
    end
    super
  end
```

My Model is

```
class StaffImage < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

it has columns
`staff_id`,
`image`,
`legacy_client_id`.

Real problem is after insertion of image in database, I can't update the image. I am new to Rails. I know problem is in this line:

`@staff_image.update_attribute('image', @staff_image.image)`

Comment: `@staff_image.update_attribute(image: params[:staff][:staff_image][:image])`

Comment: i am getting error wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)

Comment: simply use `update` instead of `update_attribute`  
`@staff_image.update(image: params[:staff][:staff_image][:image])`

Comment: still not working,showing error that undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

Comment: any one please clarify

Comment: what are the fields(columns) in `StaffImage` model?

Comment: create_table "staff_images", id: false, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
    t.integer "staff_id", null: false
    t.string "legacy_user_id"
    t.binary "image", limit: 16777215
    t.string "image_file_name"
    t.string "image_content_type"
    t.integer "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.index ["staff_id"], name: "staff_id", unique: true

Answer (score 0):

Not using any attachment plugins? Have a look on https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip gem. Way too easy for handle this kind of things in Rails.

Comment: they dont want to use any plugins

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary to use update_attribute method. Simple save could solve.

```
@staff_image.image = params[:staff]["staff_image"]["image"].read 
@staff_image.save
```

Comment: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try calling "with_indifferent_access" like:

```
params = params.with_indifferent_access
```

before accessing "staff_image"

```
params[:staff]["staff_image"]["image"]
```

this should get rid of the error and then:

```
@staff_image.image = params[:staff]["staff_image"]["image"].read 
@staff_image.save
```